# Flutter web: Prevent UI state update on browser window resize

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a flutter web page with three dropdown buttons which I use to query the database and show some objects to the user, selecting the dropdown value updates the UI as expected and modifying the variable the API needs to make the query.

The problem comes when the user resizes the browser window, that causes the UI to update again and the dropdown values revert to the default ones.

There is no error message or anything, I just want to keep the state when the screen resizes.

Is there a way for me to prevent that state change when the browser window changes its size?

or do I just let the user see that when the screen size changes, the choices made disappear and they have to select them again?

Answer (score 1):

Few options to do that:

**Option 1:** (recommended best practice)
the future variable that you use to retrieve from db should be in `initState()`. This will prevent re-querying when resizing

```
   @override void initState() {
      super.initState();
      myFuture = _dbService.get(dropDownValues);
   }
```

**Option 2:**
add a new `bool` variable `isIntendedRebuild` that you can set to `true` in your `setState()` after the drop down is updated. then, in your `build()`, add an `if` to prevent updating of your object if not intended rebuild. Do not forget to set `isIntendedRebuild` to `false` at the end of build.

```
   @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      if (intendedRebuild) {
         ///update the values of your displayed objects , otherwise dont
      }
   }
```

Comment: Did you try sending the future to initState( ) ?

Comment: Do you still need this?

Comment: I'm guessing option 2 for Riverpod UI where I just want the ExpandedTiles which are expanded to stay expanded.

Comment: But what do I return in case `intendedRebuild` is false?

Comment: You return the same code (same widget). The IF condition is just used to skip updating your objects. Disclaimer: I still did not try Riverpod yet.

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back, I'm reading everything through a provider wired up to a sidebar controller but after "fixing up" a couple of things, ie. using FittedBox, it no longer looks like a Riverpod issue.